# my wordpress website Product Description Cannot Desplay in full

Tags: wordpress

My WordPress website product descriptions cannot display in full because of the 'show more' link. I want to remove this link so that the full description shows. How can I fix this?

i tried to solve this but i connot do it .

Comment: which theme you are using?

Comment: I Used Woodmart theme.

Comment: Change the single product page design.

Comment: https://preview.themeforest.net/item/woodmart-woocommerce-wordpress-theme/full_screen_preview/20264492?_ga=2.28404988.1781828211.1708684591-412157990.1693817783&_gac=1.90716264.1708684591.Cj0KCQiAoeGuBhCBARIsAGfKY7zQ1l6oQgbZsOBDDGglXIgAklrX3m6WsZD4E8qPJh6RXyH76gBjjrsaAi-uEALw_wcB

Comment: please tell me describe. i cannot it

Comment: There are so many template are there in Woodmart theme. Check the Woodmart settings.

Comment: there are many option in Woodmart theme.this option for the solution in this issu